# IMPORTDATA function Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, import, google-sheets-formula, refresh

Does the IMPORTDATA function refresh the data automatically in GSheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, the IMPORTDATA function refresh the data automatically in GSheets.

it happens every hour.